# ngSubmit HTML attribute using angular template variable

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have two methods ngMake and ngUpdate. I have one form, PostForm. I want to reuse the same form, but add different functionality depending on the url. 
I gain information about the url using

### Controller

```
if ($location.path() === '/makepost') {
    $scope.FormTitle = 'Make a Post';
    $scope.FormAction = 'server/blog/makepost.php';
    $scope.FormMethod = 'POST';
    $scope.FormSubmit = "ngMake()"
};
if ($location.path().indexOf('update') !== -1) {
    $scope.FormTitle = 'Update a Post';
    $scope.FormAction = null;
    $scope.FormMethod = 'POST';
    $scope.FormSubmit = "ngUpdate()";
};
```

### HTML Form

```
<div ng-controller="BlogController as blog">
<h3 class="text-center">{{FormTitle}}</h3>
<form ng-show='user != null' ng-submit="{{FormSubmit}}" role="form" class="form-group" name="PostForm">
    <label>Title: </label>
    <div ng-class="(PostForm.Title.$dirty && PostForm.Title.$invalid) ? 'has-warning' : 'has-success'" class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input data-ng-model="post.Title" data-ng-minlength="3" data-ng-maxlength="255" name="Title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required/>
        <span ng-class="(PostForm.Title.$dirty && PostForm.Title.$invalid) ? 'glyphicon-warning-sign' : 'glyphicon-ok'" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <label>Content: </label>
    <div ng-class="(PostForm.Content.$dirty && PostForm.Content.$invalid) ? 'has-warning' : 'has-success'" class="form-group has-feedback">
        <textarea data-ng-model="post.Content" rows="8" name="Content" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Content" required></textarea>
        <span ng-class="(PostForm.Content.$dirty && PostForm.Content.$invalid) ? 'glyphicon-warning-sign' : 'glyphicon-ok'" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="AuthController as auth">
        <input class="ng-hide" type="number" data-ng-model="post.UserID" name="UserID" value="{{user.ID}}">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" ng-class="(PostForm.$valid) ? 'btn-success' : 'disabled'" class="btn btn-block btn-default">
</form>
<p ng-show='user == null' class="text-center">You must be <a href="#/login">logged in</a> in order to {{FormTitle | lowercase}}</p>
```

## Explination

The {{FormSubmit}} template variable probably executes afterwards and causes a problem which doesn't permit the form to execute. I am open to suggestions, I want to reuse the same form. I read that ngSubmit requires a type="submit" button or input element contained within the form tags, I have that. I do not have any ng-clicks which might hinder the form.

## I am open to suggestions

If there are any other problems with the form or the entire project please let me know, even if it is just a "bette practice".

## The full project

https://github.com/AquaSolid/RAMA_Angular_PHP

Comment: Can we have the code of the form please ?

Comment: It is not great, that your form' js-code knows about the environment: url, filenames, backend params etc. This logic should be on the backend side. If you want to reuse one form, use php-templates: change params in form by php-code.

Comment: I use the form names for form validation provided by Angular. I need Angular to gather the variables and send them over to a php file with the appropriate post method..

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I wised up. I contained the logic in the back-end. I created a function to choose which function to use. Meanwhile the the form contains the attribute `ng-submit="chooseSubmit()"`. That's about it..

```
$scope.chooseSubmit = function() {
    if ($scope.FormSubmit) {
        if ($scope.FormSubmit === 'ngMake()') {
            $scope.ngMake();
        } else {
            $scope.ngUpdate();
        };
    }
};
```